# Custom alert dialog with Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT

Tags: android

I want my user to choose my app as the default app for SMS actions.
I know I can create the alert dialog for the user to choose this app as default app by:

```
final String packageName = getActivity().getPackageName();
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,packageName);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This displays an alert Dialog with Title `"Change SMS app?"`
and contents `"Use MyAPP instead of Messaging as your SMS app?"` , which is good.

But now I want to change the title and contents of this dialog.
Is is at all possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I know. That's a system dialog. About all you can do from a regular SDK app is fire the `Intent` to open it. I don't believe that's changed on any newer versions.

Comment: Yeah, I just had a look at the source, and there's still nothing in that dialog `Activity` that's user-configurable. The only thing it accepts is the package name.